# keep privacy settings whith windows insider

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-insider

I would like to use the new [WSL 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install). That requires me to install the latest windows insider builds.

But after joining the windows insider program, it tells me that my diagnostics settings need to be "fixed". Apparently, they are too low.
Well, I guess I would be fine with windows collecting some abstract statistics on my machine. So I accepted this and then went to diagnostics to see what they are now collecting.

It has switched diagnostics from "Basic" to "Full". Among other things this means that Microsoft gets to log all websites that I visit !!!

No thanks ! I switched back to basic diagnostics, but now it doesn't allow me to install the latest windows insider builds. Is there some way around this? I thought Microsoft was on its way to being liked by devs (VS Code, open source C#, PowerShell, ...). But this is shady, especially since the dialogue prompting me to "fix" diagnostics was very high-level and didn't really show the consequences.

Comment: If you've Windows 10 Pro (stable), you can use WSL2 in a VM.

Comment: How does that work? I mean wsl is a vm itself, are we playing vm inception? And if I set up a vm for wsl, why would I want to put wsl in there, instead of Ubuntu itself?

Comment: Here is the short version: 1. Assume real machine has Windows 10 Pro stable (A) 2. Create a VM with Windows 10 pro insider (B) 3. In that VM install WSL (Ubuntu or whatever)(C). So, it goes like: Hardware --> A --> B --> C